# Oracle SQL, Calculation not going as planned

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider the following situation, [image: DataSet]

We have Apple that contains info of Apples Sold, Color gives Apple Color, Date gives the date it was sold.

I want to get Apple color, the sum of Apples sold after 2010, and the sum of apples sold after 2016 in the same row.

This is my code,

```
SELECT distinct Color, (CASE WHEN WHN >= to_date('01/01/2010','mm/dd/yyyy') 
THEN SUM(Apple) over (partition by Color) end) as tot_2010,
(CASE WHEN WHN >= to_date('01/01/2016','mm/dd/yyyy') 
THEN SUM(Apple) over (partition by Color) end) as tot_2016
from temp;
```

Now, this is the output I get

[image: Output]

Here is the desired Output

[image: Desired Output]

Here is the SQL Fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/86b932/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT color,
       SUM(CASE WHEN whn >= DATE '2010-01-01' THEN apple END) AS tot_2010,
       SUM(CASE WHEN whn >= DATE '2016-01-01' THEN apple END) AS tot_2016
FROM   temp
GROUP BY color;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
create table temp(Apple, Color,  WHN) AS
SELECT 3, 'Red',   DATE '2012-01-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9, 'Green', DATE '2014-01-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 'Red',   DATE '2017-10-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Red',   DATE '2021-02-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'Green', DATE '2020-08-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Red',   DATE '2013-03-10' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | COLOR | TOT_2010 | TOT_2016 |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Green | 16 | 7 |
> | Red | 14 | 9 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=91419a02cec8edaf12bd3ce6456d4ce9)*